# NAPTR records in DNS BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to configure NAPTR records in DNS Bind in Windows 7.

I have the following zone file:

```
$TTL 6h
@   IN  SOA     sip-udp01.example.org.  root.example.org.(

                2016010101
                10800
                3600
                604800
                86400 )
; the server where everything will run

@               NS              sip-udp01.example.org.
@               NS              sip-udp02.example.org.

sip-udp01           IN     A      127.0.0.1
sip-udp02           IN     A      127.0.0.1


_sip._udp.example.org SRV 5 100 5060 sip-udp01.example.org.
_sip._udp.example.org SRV 10 100 5060 sip-udp02.example.org.


example.org NAPTR 10 100 "S" "SIP+D2U" "" _sip._udp.example.org.
example.org NAPTR 20 100 "S" "SIP+D2T" "" _sip._tcp.example.org.
```

Bind runs successfully but I am not getting the answer.
host sip_udp01.example.org it says host sip_udp01.example.org not found.

Comment: Please update your existing question and reply in the comments if needed. The duplicate question was removed by a moderator. If you need to call my attention back to the question, please use "@Andrew" in the comment body.

Answer (score 1):

The records that you've added are improperly formatted for the zone `example.org`.  What you've actually done is define records named `_sip._udp.example.org.example.org` and `example.org.example.org`. (note the additional example.org in both cases)

Without a trailing dot, `example.org` will automatically be appended to every record you place in the zone. You must either add the trailing dot, or remove `example.org` from the individual records so that it isn't being duplicated. Removing it from the `NAPTR` records would leave you with an empty record name, so `example.org` would instead need to be replaced with `@`.